# SWIFT Json check if object title exists

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

My code checks if code: "this data" is not empty, how can I check also if code itself exists. Some responses might give me almost an empty JSON with just time stamp. So the var code won't be there.

Or is there a better way altogether to do this? as My JSON is

"Variable Based on text input" which leads to "code" which might not be there which will have "some info" or ""

Top of script:

```
struct Variables: Decodable {
  var code: String
}

typealias DecoderX = [String: Variables]
```

*Previous function sets inputs from user text which are cross checked with the database so `GetInfo` will only be called if `UserDefault` inputs are set.*

```
func GetInfo() {

  let Input1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “UserInput1”) ?? “”
  let Input2 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “UserInput2”) ?? “”
  let Input3 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “UserInput3”) ?? “”
  print(“Input Check 1: \(Input1) \(Input2) \(Input3)”)

  // URL INFO With API key hidden
  let jsonTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL) { data, response, error in
    if response == response {
      if let data = data, let body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        do {
          let json = try? decoder.decode(DeocderX.self, from: data);
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(“Input Check 2: \(json![Input1]!.code) \(json![Input2]!.code) \(json![Input3]!.code)”)
            if json?[Input1]?.code != nil {
              print("Good Information 1")
            } else {
              print("Found Nothing 1")
            }

            if json?[Input2]?.code != nil {
              print("Good Information 2")
            } else {
              print("Found Nothing 2")
            }
            if json?[Input3]?.code != nil {
              print("Good Information 3")
            } else {
              print("Found Nothing 3")
            }    
          }
        // rest of code not applicable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SwiftyJSON` library. You can find it at [this link](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
if let json = try? JSON(data: response.data!){
    if json["yourKey"]["otherKey"].exists() {
        print("exists")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: One problem I get, is when one returns with no “code” in the json then all my responses become nil as my struct is looking for raw. Is there a way to get rid of the struct ? And just parse straight in?

Comment: You can parse them with this library. "json["yourKey"]["otherKey"].int" for example.

Comment: You absolute champion, how has no one told be about this before! I’m using all the nested struct and cases! All I needed was to add swiftyJSON !

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding. Also you can have more information about this library from it's documents :)